# Поиск файла в нескольких директориях. try_files в location NGINX

Tags: nginx

Подскажите, у меня статичные файлы могут лежать в папке `/var/www/project/storage/downloads`, либо в `/var/www/project/public/downloads`.

Мне нужно, чтобы при обращении по адресу `http://localhost/downloads/img.jpg` файл сначала искался в папке `/var/www/project/storage/downloads`, потом в папке `/var/www/project/public/downloads` и только в случае, если его нигде нет, выкидывалась ошибка 403. В моем случае это почему-то не работает (в папке `/var/www/project/public/downloads` файл есть, в `/var/www/project/storage/downloads` нет)

Вот мой конфиг:

```
events {}

http {
   include mime.types;

   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      root /var/www/project/public/;

      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

      location / {
          try_files $uri =404;
      }

      location /downloads/ {
          root /var/www/project/storage/;
          try_files $uri /var/www/project/public/$uri =403;
          access_log off;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: try_files нужно передавать URI, а не пути на диске

Comment: `root /var/www/project; try_files $uri /storage/$uri /public/$uri =404;`

Comment: @nörbörnën, первый $uri лишний

Comment: @AlexeyTen угу_